# Call to a member function isSuperUser() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have added this method to my User model:

```
public function isSuperUser()
{
    return $this->is_superuser;
}
```

`is_superuser` is a column of my `users` table which is set to Boolean type.

And then I created this middleware to check if the authenticated user is admin (super user) or not:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->user()->isSuperUser()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

And I have applied this middleware to all the admin routes in `RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```
Route::middleware('auth.admin')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->prefix('admin')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web/admin.php'));
```

But now when I load one of the admin routes I get this error:

**Call to a member function isSuperUser() on null**

However I am already logged in to my account.

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Show us how you registered your middleware in `app\Http\Kernel.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assume that user is not logged so you should use:

```
if($request->user()?->isSuperUser()) {
   return $next($request);
}
```

or

```
if(optional($request->user())->isSuperUser()) {
   return $next($request);
}
```

if you are using older PHP versions

Comment: I just tested this but still shows the error

Comment: @japose7523 So you must be running this method in some other place too

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead.

```php
// ...

if(auth()->user()?->is_superuser)

// ...
```

Comment: I just tested and still shows the same error